# Safari cuts Entypo icons

Tags: fonts, safari, icons

I'm trying to use Entypo icon, but I've this problem in Safari on Mac OS X (Mavericks) — http://take.ms/NdZhs

For some reason icon got cuted. Everything works fine in Chrome, though.

CSS:

```
.showblock .title {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    .showblock .title:before {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          font-family: 'entypo';
          font-size: 60px;
          line-height: 30px;
    }

.icon-behance:before {
    content: "\F34E";
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="title icon-dribbble">Dribbble Playground</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been corrected by a contributor. Download from Git here:

https://github.com/danielbruce/entypo